# Scala pass in integer comparator to function

Tags: scala

```
def readf(value_name: String, operator:operand, compared_value:Int  f:()=>Unit) {
```

I want to look up an Int in a HashMap based on the value_name String passed in. Taking that value I want to compare it

value operator compared_value

if that statement is true I want to execute f.

How do I pass in a comparator and evaluate this logic? Preferably without writing my own classes.

Comment: Can you give an example for an "operand"? It's difficult to understand what you are trying to do. Would an operand just be a function `(Int, Int) => Boolean` ?

Comment: Downvoting because ypu keep posting questions with little to no effort to make the question clear, readable, correctly formatted, etc. The result is that people are struggling to understand your question. Please make an effort yourself if you expect random strangers to make an effort for you.

Answer (score 0):

The result from the HashMap can be as an Option which you can then filter with the operand/compared_value.  Then it should be just a map on the resulting option. It would look something like:

```
yourMap.get(value_name).filter(_ operator compared_value).map(f)
```

This does assume that operator is (Int, Int) => Boolean as asked in the comment

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to help with the editorial issues your question has, but I'll try. Assuming you have a `myMap: Map[String, Int]` in scope (which your question does not show) and assuming your operator is really of type `(Int, Int) => Boolean`, you could do:

```
scala> val myMap = Map("test" -> 8)
myMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(test -> 8)

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def readf(value_name: String, operator: (Int, Int) => Boolean, compared_value:Int, f:()=>Unit) {
   myMap.get(value_name).filter(operator(_, compared_value)).foreach(_ => f())
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

readf: (value_name: String, operator: Int => (Int => Boolean), compared_value: Int, f: () => Unit)Unit

scala> val eqComparator = ((_: Int) == (_: Int))
eqComparator: (Int, Int) => Boolean = <function2>

scala> val f = () => println("success")
f: () => Unit = <function0>

scala> readf("test", eqComparator, 8, f)
success

scala> readf("test", eqComparator, 5, f)

scala> readf("other", eqComparator, 8, f)
```

(Edited to remove the curried operator. It's probably clearer this way.)